# VSTS API - Accessing team rooms throws 401 error

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I'm trying to access the Team rooms functionality in Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS)
With a valid token if I make a request to :
https://.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/chat/rooms?api-version=1.0

I get an error 401. I have tested the token and I can make requests to other endpoints without an issue.

```
status code: 401, headers {
    "Content-Length" = 10828;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Fri, 17 Feb 2017 09:36:17 GMT";
    Server = "Microsoft-IIS/10.0";
    "Strict-Transport-Security" = "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";
    "Www-Authenticate" = Bearer;
    p3p = "CP=\"CAO DSP COR ADMa DEV CONo TELo CUR PSA PSD TAI IVDo OUR SAMi BUS DEM NAV STA UNI COM INT PHY ONL FIN PUR LOC CNT\"";
    "x-content-type-options" = nosniff;
    "x-frame-options" = SAMEORIGIN;
    "x-powered-by" = "ASP.NET";
    "x-tfs-processid" = "925585e2-35c8-4691-b646-c96e48f04ee0";
    "x-tfs-serviceerror" = "TF400813%3a+Resource+not+available+for+anonymous+access.+Client+authentication+required.";
    "x-tfs-soapexception" = "%3c%3fxml+version%3d%221.0%22+encoding%3d%22utf-8%22%3f%3e%3csoap%3aEnvelope+xmlns%3asoap%3d%22http%3a%2f%2fwww.w3.org%2f2003%2f05%2fsoap-envelope%22%3e%3csoap%3aBody%3e%3csoap%3aFault%3e%3csoap%3aCode%3e%3csoap%3aValue%3esoap%3aReceiver%3c%2fsoap%3aValue%3e%3csoap%3aSubcode%3e%3csoap%3aValue%3eInvalidIdentityException%3c%2fsoap%3aValue%3e%3c%2fsoap%3aSubcode%3e%3c%2fsoap%3aCode%3e%3csoap%3aReason%3e%3csoap%3aText+xml%3alang%3d%22en%22%3eTF400813%3a+Resource+not+available+for+anonymous+access.+Client+authentication+required.%3c%2fsoap%3aText%3e%3c%2fsoap%3aReason%3e%3c%2fsoap%3aFault%3e%3c%2fsoap%3aBody%3e%3c%2fsoap%3aEnvelope%3e";
    "x-vss-s2stargetservice" = "00000002-0000-8888-8000-000000000000/visualstudio.com";
} })
```

Comment: show the request as raw content: is the token passed appropriately? You need to have a well formed request of course

Comment: Be aware that Team Rooms are being deprecated. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2017/01/04/deprecation-of-the-team-rooms-in-team-services-and-tfs/

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant application the **Team rooms (read and write)** permission.

[image]

So, check the application you registered whether has the Team rooms (read and write) scope. Also check the web application config file (web.config) whether there is **vso.chat_write** in Scope (key) value.

For example:

```
<add key="Scope" value="vso.agentpools vso.build vso.chat_write vso.code vso.dashboards vso.identity vso.packaging vso.release vso.test vso.work"/>
```